# Characterize all $C^{\infty}$ functions such that $f\delta^{'}=0$.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Find all function $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, such that $f\delta^{'}=0$ ,where $\delta^{'}$ is a distribution known as the dipole distribution defined as follows
$$\delta^{'}:D(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}$$ as $\delta^{'}(\phi)=\phi^{'}(0)$.

My attempt: We have $f\delta^{'}(\phi)=0$ for all $\phi \in D(\mathbb{R})$. So by definition, we have $\delta^{'}(f\phi)=0 \implies (f\phi)^{'}(0)=0 \implies f^{'}(0)\phi(0)+ \phi^{'}(0)f(0)=0 $. Now we can choose $\phi \in D(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\phi(0)=0, \phi^{'}(0)=1$, so that gives $f(0)=0$. Now next what  I have in mind is that I can choose another $\phi \in D(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\phi(0)=1, \phi^{'}(0)=0$. Then it will gives $f^{'}(0)=0$. So I have all those $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f(0)=0, f^{'}(0)=0$. Can I have a nicer characterization of $f$, a more nice looking family? Also I want to know whether my first choice of $\phi$ is valid or not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $f(0)=f'(0) = 0$ is the only possible characterization, equivalently $f(x) = \mathcal{O}(x^2)$

Comment: What about the second choice of $\phi$? Can we get such a $\phi$ with compact support and infinitely many times differentiable?

Comment: Look at $\varphi(x) = \int_{-2}^2 e^{-1/(1-(x-y)^2)}1_{|x-y| < 1} dy$ that belongs to $C_c^\infty$ and is constant and non-zero on $[-1,1]$. Thus you can multiply it with any $C^\infty$ function to obtain any sequence of derivatives at the origin.

Comment: sorry I have edited the question, there is n problem with the second $\phi$, but what about the first $\phi$, that I chose , that  is $\phi \in D(\mathbb{R})$, with $\phi(0)=0 , \phi^{'}(0)=1$? Can we have such function.

Comment: Yes this is what I told you, $x \frac{\varphi(x)}{\varphi(0)}$ is such a function.

Comment: Ok got it!! thanks!!

Comment: You can write $f (x) = x^2 g (x) $ for some $g \in C^\infty (\mathbb R) $.